# Where can I find the interpreter/compiler of Dart language?

Tags: windows, dart

How can I run a Dart application? Do I need a VM as in Java?

I tried to embed the following code on a html page:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="application/dart">
      main() {
        Element element = document.getElementById('message');
        element.innerHTML = 'Hello from Dart';
      }     
    </script>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work - it returns the pure HTML on the page. What am I doing wrong?
My Google Chrome version: `Chrome/14.0.835.202` and my platform is Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download Dart binaries for Windows (`dart_bin.exe`) and Linux from [Installing Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install).

You can write a small Hello World, `hello.dart`:

```
main() {
    print('Hello World');
}
```

Then you execute the Dart-script with:

```
C:\Users\Jonas\dart>dart_bin hello.dart
Hello World
```

Comment: @The Mask: Yes, but `dart_bin` is for server side, so the libraries e.g. for accessing the DOM is not included. I think we have to build `dartc` and use the Eclipse plugin to be able to test client side scripts.

Comment: As of today you can run the above shown Hello world program with dart.exe located in dart-sdk\bin.

Answer (score 5):

Dart's only in an early developer preview stage right now. In some cases, the implementation, specification and documentation contradict each other!

Google is probably going to add Dart support to Chrome in the future, but this is a long-term objective, and hasn't been implemented yet.

You need to download and compile the Dart interpreter/compiler yourself. Dart's Google Code project's wiki has an entry about this, [Building Dart](http://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Building), but like the rest of the documentation it's somewhat sparse at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Currently there are a few options available:

- Run sample code in the Dartboard window at [dartlang.org](http://www.dartlang.org/)
- [Build dartc compiler](http://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Building) and run provided [htmlconverter.py script](http://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/HTMLConverter) which will translate an HTML page with yours `application/dart` blocks into an HTML page with JavaScript code
- [Build the standalone VM](http://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Building#Building_the_standalone_VM) and run Dart code in it
- Wait until Google Chrome will support Dart natively

**Update #1**

- [It was announced](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/group/misc/browse_thread/thread/a938fcc42e83fc5b#) that Dart (only small subset in fact) now runs on JVM 7 (using [Dart to JVM bytecode](http://code.google.com/p/jdart/) compiler).

**Update #2**

- Instead of building *dartc* compiler from the sources you can download [Dart Editor](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/getting-started/editor/), an editor based on Eclipse components which supports Dart-to-JavaScript compilation.
- [Frog](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/group/misc/msg/9b5c53dceb83ad90) is a new Dart compiler written in Dart; while it was only started recently and still contains some bugs, it generates much more optimized JS code and runs [significantly faster](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/dart-to-js-compilation-with-frog/) than *dartc*.

**Update #3**

- Now there is available Chromium with native Dart VM - *[Dartium](http://www.dartlang.org/dartium/)*, but only in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

To make Dart code runnable in the browser you have to transpile it to JavaScript first except for the Dart development browser Dartium which has a Dart VM integrated.

One way is to use `dart2js`.

A more comfortable way is to use `pub build`. If you project structure is according to the [Pub Package Layout Conventions](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html) just running `pub build` builds your entire project with multiple entry pages.
Some framework require transformers (code generation) and `pub build` ensures the transformers process your source files before passing them to `dart2js`.

To run Dart scripts outside the browser just run `dart path/to/my_script.dart`